# Loading functions off another child class fails when parent construct fails to load

Tags: php, class

I have a set of classes and a global file that calls them to create the "engine" for my website. When I make a call to the "engine" on any user created page, it lets me call the defined functions and template functions properly. I define my engine as `$system` throughout the script. When I want to call from one of the children classes, I `global $system` to be able to load the data.

Here is the basic ***global.php*** layout

```
include_once("class.system.php");
$system = new Main;
.. timezone stuff, session settings, etc ...
```

I am loading the **Main** class (the file ***class.system.php***) with this file (***global.php***) and setting some other variables like session and timezone stuff with the ***global.php*** file which is included in all the user created files to link them to the `engine`. The ***class.system.php*** is the parent class or core engine file that will load the children sub classes, which are **Functions**, **Templates**, and **Configuration**. Eventually this will include plugins, users, and other addon classes to tie everything together.

Here is **Main** class (the file ***class.system.php***) that I call from my ***global.php***. Once included I *CAN* call all my template files and my functions, and config, etc, from the user created file.

```
include_once("class.configuration.php");
include_once("class.functions.php");
include_once("class.templates.php");
class Main {
    function __construct(){
        $this->config = new Configuration;
        $this->function = new Functions;
        $this->template = new Templates;
        $this->db = mysqli_connect($this->config->db['hostname'], $this->config->db['db_username'], $this->config->db['db_password']);
        if (!$this->db || $this->db->connect_errno > 0) {
            $this->template->load_template_file("errors/sql.connect");
            die();
        }
        $connection = mysqli_select_db($this->db, $this->config->db['database']);
    }
}
```

This adds the functions `$system->config`, `$system->function`, and `$system->template` which can be used ON the user created function. Now the issue I am having is calling functions from say.. `$system->function` in the **Templates** class.

If the database is unable to connect and the `$this->template->load_template_file(..);` function is called, it is unable, even using a `global $system;` call, to load anything from the **Functions** or **Configurations** classes. IF, however, the database succeeds to be called and the script loads properly, I am then able to load all of the content from both directions and have full access to the functions and templates and configuration data in all three classes.

Now, the reason this is all an issue is I am calling a template file if the SQL fails to connect. The template file, normally, would inject data or replace data over certain keywords like this:

```
public function load_template_file(..) {
    global $system;
    $replace = array (
        '%%YEAR%%' => date("Y"),
        '%%COMPANY%%' => $system->config->settings['meta_author'],
        '%%SUPPORT%%' => $system->function->bar()
    );
    $template = $this->replace_in_file($replace, $template);
    .... more code to display stuff here ...
}
```

but since the other classes aren't loaded into memory because the construct failed due to the database losing connection, the injected variables fail, we get a white page instead of the error template, and the following error is generated:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bar() on null in (path..)
```

if the database successfully connects and the `__construct` method passes, we can global those variables and it instead works and throws no errors.

What is the solutions for this error? I have tried extending the sub classes from  Main but that didn't make a difference. When I tried to include the functions class in the templates class, it throws an error because Functions has already been defined as a class by **Main**, but it's not accessible to the Templates because the constructor has failed.

Here is a final brief example of the other three classes as well

```
class Configuration {
    function __construct() {}
    $db = array (
        'setting' => 'value'
    );
}

class Functions {
    function __construct() {}
    public function bar() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

class Templates {
    function __construct() {}
    .. see the load_template_file method above ..
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `$system`? Use `$this->function->bar();`

Comment: because the function class is NOT the same file as the Template class, that `load_template_file` function is a template function in a different class so referencing $this doesn't know where the member function for bar() is.

Comment: Sorry there is a lot to try and follow - BUT I have big concerns as to why you have `global $system;` anywhere in a class.

Comment: It's the only way I could get access to the functions classes from within my templates class file. Since the system is define as $system, I just call that global variable to load my functions. How else would I access them? I am unsure of the correct way to load them or the config variables onto my other classes and extending them did not work.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I have edited this answer to make a better answer with proper code**

The issue I was having was the classes were not properly declared to each other. I was able to fix this by adding the following code to each class file:

```
private $function;
private $config;

function __construct() {}

public function setDependencies($function, $config) {
    $this->function = $function;
    $this->config = $config;
}
```

This is a snippet from the `Templates` class. I did the exact same thing on the `Functions` class, except I swapped the `private $function` for a `private $template`. Now on my ***class.system.php*** I am calling both files like so:

```
$this->config = new Configuration;
$this->function = new Functions;
$this->template = new Templates;
$this->function->setDependencies($this->template, $this->config);
$this->template->setDependencies($this->function, $this->config);
```

What this is doing is setting the values of each child into the class for use. I am able to eliminate the need for any Global variables like I was using before and create multi-dependency classes.

Thanks for all your help guys!